# Installing dotnet8 on amazonlinux 2023 image through dockerfile

Tags: .net, dockerfile, containers, amazon-linux-2023

I am trying to install dotnet8 on amazon linux 2023 image public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:2023. After installing, one of the command that it tries to run is 'dotnet', but it errors out saying:

> /bin/sh: line 1: dotnet: command not found

Below is the block of code that i am running to install dotnet:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:2023

RUN curl -fSL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-linux-arm64.tar.gz \
&& echo "dotnet.tar.gz" \
&& mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
&& tar -oxzf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet ./packs ./sdk ./sdk-manifests ./templates ./LICENSE.txt ./ThirdPartyNotices.txt \
&& rm dotnet.tar.gz \
&& ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet \
# Trigger first run experience by running arbitrary cmd
&& dotnet help
```

But when i loginto the container through *docker run* command and check for *dotnet info* I get below details:

> bash-5.2# dotnet --info .NET SDK:  Version:           8.0.203  Commit:
> 5e1ceea679  Workload version:  8.0.200-manifests.4e94be9c
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     amzn  OS Version:  2023  OS
> Platform: Linux  RID:         linux-arm64  Base Path:
> /var/lang/bin/sdk/8.0.203/
>
> .NET workloads installed: There are no installed workloads to display.
>
> Host:   Version:      8.0.3   Architecture: arm64   Commit:
> 9f4b1f5d66
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 8.0.203 [/var/lang/bin/sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.3
> [/var/lang/bin/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.3
> [/var/lang/bin/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> Other architectures found:   None
>
> Environment variables:   DOTNET_ROOT       [/var/lang/bin]
>
> global.json file:   Not found
>
> Learn more:   https://aka.ms/dotnet/info
>
> Download .NET:   https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Not sure what is missing in the dockerfile. Any help/input would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks